A way to tell the immediate runtime that invoked a `.ps1`
I want to be able to tell whether a shell calling my script is either bash or powershell. I've attempted to do this via $MyInvocation and seeing the $PPID, but neither give any clues.
test.ps1
#!/bin/pwsh
$MyInvocation
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Parent

Here I first run a script from a bash interactive session, then immediately from a powershell instance. They aren't really distinguishable, I do understand why, but is there a way this can be done?


I should add I've also attempted dot-sourcing and & ./test.ps1ing from within pwsh (even though this would not robustly solve my problem) but it's no different.

What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

@MathiasR.Jessen "I want to be able to tell whether a shell calling my script is either bash or powershell"

There does not be a new pwsh process when you start the script. To start a new process you could do: Start-Process pwsh -ArgumentList "./test.ps1" -Wait  (see: PowerShell script to open a new PowerShell window and run command )

I dont want to start a new process, note the "I do understand why [this attempt did not work]", but how can it be done @Luuk

@Luuk I suppose, conversely; is there a way to tell if pwsh was started as a new process instance (id est, bash calling the script) or running inside a pre-existing powershell environment (pwsh running the script directly)?

Look at: (Get-Process -id $PID) | fl Name,Commandline,ProcessName, which seems to return pwsh when started from pwsh, and something else when started from bash.

@Hashbrown, I think Mathias may be asking why do you need to determine what the calling shell is as there may be other solutions to your problem without determining whether the script is called from bash shell, powershell or something else.

Note the caller might not even be a shell - it could be a dotnet / c# application using the System.Management.Automation library as well…

@Daniel if in bash write suggestions to the user like ln -s 'somefile'\''withapostrophy' $name or if pwsh write out ln -s 'somefile''withapostrophy' $name. I doubt there's an alternate solution. Regardless the question itself also is something worth answering if powershell literally lacks the expressive power to implement it at all..

I'm well aware @mclayton, I have power over how the script can be utilised by the users

@mclayton I mean, inversely, if this is possible, then it opens up a possibility to bar people from running the script non-interactively, which could be a valid usecase for someone (throw runtime error if detecting parent process is unrecognised C# executable)



Even files with (PowerShell) shebang lines are executed in-process by PowerShell if their names have a .ps1 extension, both from the stand-alone PowerShell host (CLI), pwsh, and when using the PowerShell SDK to host PowerShell in a custom application.

By contrast, extension-less shebang-based scripts are always run in a child process, i.e. even when invoked from a PowerShell host. Unfortunately, due to a bug still present as of v7.4.2 (current as of this writing), extension-less scripts lack information about their own file path and directory (that is, $PSCommandPath and $PSScriptRoot aren't populated): see GitHub issue #4217

For guidance on whether to use .ps1 or omit an extension when naming a shebang-based PowerShell script, see this answer.



You can detect whether a shebang-based PowerShell file is being run in its own process, i.e. is being run from a non-PowerShell host, by whether $MyInvocation.Line is empty, for instance.

As your screenshots demonstrate, .Line (as well as .Statement and .PositionMessage) is not filled in when a shebang-based PowerShell script is invoked from outside PowerShell, because these properties refer to PowerShell-specific call-site information, which is N/A in this scenario.


In the latter case, you can use [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Parent (or (Get-Process -ID $PID).Parent) to determine (the path of) the process that invoked the dedicated PowerShell child process.


The following script determines whether a given invocation happened in-process in a regular PowerShell session, in-process via the SDK, or in a child process via the shebang line (from outside PowerShell, such as from bash), and also outputs the parent process' path:
#!/usr/bin/env -S pwsh -noprofile

$thisProcess = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess()
[pscustomobject] @{
  RunningVia = 
    if ($MyInvocation.Line) {
      'In-process, in PowerShell session'
    } elseif ($thisProcess.MainModule.ModuleName -eq 'pwsh') {
      'In a child process, via the shebang line'
    } else {
      'In-process, via the PowerShell SDK'
    }
  ParentProcess = $thisProcess.Parent.Path
}

Assuming the above was saved to file test.ps1 in the current directory and the file was made executable (chmod a+x test.ps1), invoking ./test.ps1 from bash outputs:
RunningVia                               ParentProcess
----------                               -------------
In a child process, via the shebang line /bin/bash

If all you need to know is whether the script was being run via its shebang line, from a non-PowerShell host, in a dedicated PowerShell child process, you can use the following.
$runningViaShebangLine =
  -not $MyInvocation.Line -and 
  [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName -eq 'pwsh'

If you don't need to detect the SDK invocation scenario,
$runningViaShebangLine = -not $MyInvocation.Line alone is enough.
Note that the following, simpler test:
# !! See LIMITATIONS below
$runningViaShebangLine =
  [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Name -eq (Split-Path -Leaf $PSCommandPath)

works only:

fundamentally only on Linux (not also on macOS)
even there only if the pwsh binary is invoked directly via the shebang line, not via /usr/bin/env, as shown above.

Read on for details.

Portable shebang lines, behavior of [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Name:

Instead of hard-coding the path to the pwsh binary, the above shebang line invokes pwsh via /usr/bin/env, which in turn requires that the target pwsh be the (first one) in $env:PATH

The advantage of this approach is portability: the script will also work on systems with a different PowerShell installation directory; note that even the default installation directory differs between macOS and Linux.

The -S option in the above shebang line (#!/usr/bin/env -S pwsh -noprofile ) is required due to the Linux system-level limitation of accepting only two arguments in a shebang line: also passing -noprofile (i.e. suppressing profile loading, which is advisable for both performance reasons and to make for a predictable execution environment) or any additional arguments amounts to at least three arguments in combination with /usr/bin/env; -S tells the latter to perform its own splitting of whatever comes after into distinct arguments.



Using /usr/bin/env (which replaces itself with the pwsh process it creates, so that env does not appear as the pwsh process' parent), has one side effect, however:

On Linux - but not on macOS - it seems that the process for the immediately invoked binary specified in the shebang line causes [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Name to reflect the file name of the script file (rather than the name of the interpreter binary it was passed to), i.e. test.ps1 in the case at hand (which can be queried dynamically via Split-Path -Leaf $PSCommandPath).

Therefore, this does not apply when /usr/bin/env mediates the invocation of pwsh, in which case [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Name then reports pwsh (as it always does on macOS).

The code above works around this problem, by accessing .MainModule.ModuleName rather than .Name on [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess(), which always reports  'pwsh', and therefore works in all invocation scenarios, on both Linux and macOS.





That's a nice workaround, forcing a new process. I actually didn't think to try CurrentProcess (non-parent thereof) because I assumed it would be pwsh both times. In actuality, without the env pwsh redirect, from-bash reports [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Name to be test.ps1 and from-pwsh reports pwsh; so that's just usable as-is!

I can't upvote my own answer, so I may have to swap around who gets the tick and give this answer an upvote instead

PS I do like that powershell does not run scripts in their own process. It's more efficient and it's in stark contrast to bash who likes to open subshells even just for encapsulating parentheses.. For the type of script I'm working with though I'd be happy to have made it its own process to get it working anyway

@Hashbrown: Your approach only works on Linux, not also on macOS - though maybe that's all you need. Please see my update, especially the new bottom section.

@Hashbrown: Yes, it's generally a plus that PowerShell runs its script in-process, especially given the high startup cost of a PowerShell child process (there is no concept of subshells in PowerShell). On the flip side, it means that scripts can affect the global session state, which is especially annoying with Set-Location calls.

@Hashbrown: If you want your .ps1 file to be shebang-based, i.e. directly executable from outside PowerShell, you need to design it in a way that anticipates the data-type limitations and the inability to pass arrays in outside calls - this answer discusses these tradeoffs.

Yeah it is strange regarding cd and such that it's not sandboxed. I thought that was the whole point of being able to dot-source like you can with scriptblocks. No need to worry about passing data, it's meant to be called like a script file; only strings, standard stdin/out stuff

@Hashbrown: Understood. I forgot to mention that the in-process execution is also problematic in the opposite direction: unlike in Bash, aliases are also in effect in scripts, so it's easy to fool a script with something like function Get-ChildItem { 'psych!' }. That's why suppression of profile-loading is important in CLI calls (which are implicitly used when invoking shebang-based scripts), and it is quite unfortunate that this requires opt-in (unlike in Bash et. al.), via -NoProfile

Use the current process, not the parent
#!/bin/pwsh
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Name


When spawned as its own process (id est, not running under a pwsh runtime) the script's own name is reported. Inside pwsh it will report "pwsh".
